# Is there the equivent of a Java Set in php?

Tags: java, php, collections, set

Is there the equivalent of a Java Set in php?

(meaning a collection that can't contain the same element twice)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could just use an array and put the data you want in the key because keys can't be duplicated.

Answer (score 6):

You can use a standard PHP array of values, and pass it through [array_unique](http://ch.php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php) function:

```
$input = array(4, "4", "3", 4, 3, "3");
$result = array_unique($input);
var_dump($result);
```

Outputs:

```
array(2) {
  [0] => int(4)
  [2] => string(1) "3"
}
```

Answer (score 5):

[SplObjectStorage](http://php.net/manual/en/class.splobjectstorage.php) is the closest thing.

```
$storage = new SplObjectStorage;
$obj1    = new StdClass;

$storage->attach($obj1);
$storage->attach($obj1); // not attached
echo $storage->count();  // 1

$obj2    = new StdClass; // different instance
$obj3    = clone($obj2); // different instance

$storage->attach($obj2);
$storage->attach($obj3);    
echo $storage->count();  // 3
```

As the name implies, this is only working with *objects* though. If you'd want to use this with scalar types, you'd have to use the new [Spl Types](http://php.net/manual/en/book.spl-types.php) as a replacement, as well as the [Spl Data Structures](http://php.net/manual/en/spl.datastructures.php) and [ArrayObject](http://php.net/manual/en/class.arrayobject.php) for Array replacements.